# What is this food "cr of leek and pot 21814"?

Tags: food-identification

I was given some food, one of which is named "cr of leek and pot 21814"
[image]

I am not sure what it is. Can anyone tell me how to cook it? Is it vegetable, staple, or  ...?

should I store it in freezer or the warmer part of a refrigerator?

Comment: Well... as a note, the 21814 is probably a use by date, so... that means it's nearly two years past date (assuming Feb 18, 2014) or a year and a half past date (assuming Aug. 21st, 2014). I don't know that I'd want to eat it...

Comment: @Catija It's actually the product code. If it's been kept frozen then it'll be safe to eat indefinitely.

Comment: @RossRidge If it's the product code, that's good... but even frozen stuff can go bad if you have a frost-free freezer.

Comment: It says on the package "condensed frozen soup" "keep frozen until ready to use" and "this product may be tempered up to 5 days in a 40F refrigerator prior to cooking." There are also specific directions for how to cook it. So I understand asking what exactly it is ("leek & pot" isn't obvious if you're not from a part of the world where leek and potato is common, though you can find out from Google very easily) but the rest of the question does seem to show some lack of research effort, as it were.

Answer (score 7):

[Google suggested](https://www.google.com/search?q=cr%20of%20leek%20and%20pot) it's a **CR**eam **OF LEEK** and **POT**ato soup.

Just follow the instructions on the package to cook this dish. Apparently it is only half-way cooked. Empty the tray into a pot, add as much water as the tray holds to the pot. Heat the soup until it boils, stir frequently. Then, reduce the heat and let it simmer. The package says something with 100°F (?), I can't read it.

If the package is still frozen, you can leave it frozen in the freezer; otherwise you can leave this package up to 5 days at 40°F in the refrigerator prior cooking (as the package says).

Comment: Thanks. Am I supposed to have it for one meal, without anything else?

Comment: @Tim Of course you can eat the soup only for one meal. I have no idea how large the tray is - you have to estimate how much soup you like to eat. If the soup alone is not enough, you can eat some warm bread with the soup.

Comment: @Tim It's a 3/4 pound "foodservice" tub of Campbell's frozen condensed soup. It's designed for restaurants and institutions and is meant to provide many servings of soup. You'll need a large pot to cook it in, twice the volume of the tub. You'll probably won't want to eat it all at one sitting. You can store the remainder in the fridge (up to 5 days) and reheat it when you want to have some more. It's basically just like a can of Campbell's condensed soup except there's a lot more of it and for long term storage it should be stored in the freezer.